# I would like to be able to sort answers in different orders in wiki and non-wiki questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

In wiki questions, which are usually subjective, I want to see the most popular answer bubble to the top. But in questions that are not subjective or only have a few posts, I sort by oldest first (to see how the answers developed). On top of this, I would also like to disable the "accepted answer on top" feature, since that ruins my flow of reading the development of an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Put me down as against it. Allowing this would encourage the idea that wiki means it is OK to treat SO/SF/SU as a discussion forum.

Accepted questions get special treatment to encourage the idea that these sites are for *helping people to solve problems*. Which is as it should be.

Comment: Then what is the point of wiki, if not to build a reference section of sorts.

Comment: Building a reference section is all well and good, but all questions are or should be that way. There are more than a few users who seem to believe that wiki questions are fundamentally different, and have the attitude "If I make it wiki it doesn't *have* to be on topic." I don't want to encourage that idea.

Comment: Reference Section != Discussion Section. Discussion topics have no value, period. Aka, how do I decide which headphones to buy.